# Stream, filter, grouping by and sum for columns in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm new to Java, trying to achieve the below result:

| image 1 | image 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

**Result should**  (All the row should get merge in 1 line for each account/Type/Currency

```
List<aggregateGeneral> s = new ArrayList<>();                           
Map<String, List<aggregateGeneral>> currencyGroup = 
aggregateGeneralDataList.stream()                           
    .filter(a -> StringUtils.equals("General", a.getgeneral()))                         
    . collect(Collectors.groupingBy(aggregateGeneral::getcurrency));
```

It is working up to groupingby.
Can someone help me achieve the final result, please?

Comment: This code abandons a lot of coding conventions so it is ugly to read and harder to understand. What the code lacks is that it does not check for the three required properties account/Type/Currency. https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector in 2.3 / 2.5 has a good hint on how to get there.

Comment: What you might be looking for is using the `toMap` collectors. You would need to define a `mergeFn(AggregateGeneral one, AggregateGeneral two)` for it to be used.

Comment: @JayC667, It is pulling list for account, Type, currency in JSon Format. I'm struggling to figure out once it's fitered, grouped by then how would I sum all and reduce to 1 line